# Control inner container scroll from overall document

Tags: css, layout, scroll, css-position

[image: screenshot]

What is the best way to achieve this effect? Scroll on any part of the document should scroll the inner container.

In this demo, all top-level components have `position: fixed` with hardcoded positions and widths. Seems rather inflexible.

We could have a regular (non-`position: fixed`) layout, listen to scroll events on the top-level container and trigger those on the inner container. That requires keeping the outer scrollbar in sync and seems error-prone.

What's the best way to think about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think its best to stick scroll on `inner container` than the `whole document`, for example your page is long or very long it would conflict scrolling the inner container with the whole document, unless otherwise your page is fit to browser window -which doe's not need scrolling, then you can use inner scrolling.

I you are sticking for whole document scroll here is an example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qndjW/6/